# How can I use conditional formatting or a macro to italicize duplicates (but not the original) cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, conditional-formatting, duplicate

I have a spreadsheet in which there are many duplicates (intentionally), and I would like to highlight the duplicates but not the first instance of a cell. Below is an example row:

A *A A A A* B *B B* C *C C C C*

These duplicates are all in rows, and I basically want the first (left-most) of each item to stand out. In an ideal world, I would actually change the color of the text of each of the duplicates as well to a dark grey while leaving the first instance in black and unitalicized.

I'm inexperienced in conditional formatting and writing macros but have been exploring a bit in reference to this project.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. We are not a script writing service. We expect users to tell us what they have tried so far (including any scripts they are using) and where they're stuck so that we can help with specific problems. Questions that only ask for scripts are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Relevant meta for close voters: http://meta.superuser.com/q/10752/76571

Answer (score 1):

With conditional formatting:

- Select the row containing your data
- go to: Home - conditional formatting - new rule - use a formula to decide...
- if your data is in row 1, starting at A1, then enter this formula:
  `=COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)>1`
- specify the condition you need (italic, font colour...)

### Update

If you want to format multiple rows based on hear row's contender, then according to Excellll's suggestion:

select all the rows and use the slightly different formula `=COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)>1`

Comment: I think she has multiple rows like this. Your approach could be amended to fit this need if you select all the rows and use the slightly different formula `=COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)>1`.